# Keeping connection alive in the right way from c# client

Tags: c#, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I have a self hosted signalr hub and two types of clients those connect to it.

- Web apps: I can keep connection state as you see below using the disconnected event:

  ```
  $(function () {
      $.connection.hub.url = "http://localhost:8080/signalr";

      // Declare a proxy to reference the hub.
      var priceHub = $.connection.uTHub;

      $.connection.hub.start();

      $.connection.hub.disconnected(function () {
          setTimeout(function () {
              $.connection.hub.start();
          }, 2000); // Restart connection after 2 seconds.
      });
  });
  ```
- Windows services:

  ```
      hubConnection = new HubConnection("http://localhost:8080/signalr", "source=" + feed, useDefaultUrl: false);
      priceProxy = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("UTHub");
      hubConnection.Start().Wait();
  ```

In windows services, how can I handle the disconnected event (Restarting connection after 2 seconds behaviour) as I used in web apps?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/handling-connection-lifetime-events#keepalive this logic is already mentioned in your question. What you trying to fix than?

Comment: Yes I know that I have that logic in my web application clients of my hub. I need the same logic for my windows service clients of my hub.

Comment: The answer - it's not possible.

Comment: Yes, it is. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what I need:

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-net-client#connectionlifetime

```
        hubConnection.Closed += () => {
            connected = false;
            while (!connected)
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
                hubConnection = new HubConnection("http://localhost:8080/signalr", "source=" + feed, useDefaultUrl: false);
                priceProxy = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("UTHub");
                hubConnection.Start().Wait();
                connected = true;
            }
        };
```

Comment: don't you need a try catch in there?

Answer (score 0):

to perform custom logic when disc a client gets disconnected is to override ondisconnected method on hub class, like this:

```
public override Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled)
    {
        // your custom code here...
        return base.OnDisconnected(stopCalled);
    }
```

Comment: Yes but I want my client to reconnect to hub by itself if it disconnects. I think this is not an answer to my question.

Comment: the server can not connect to client before any request from the client and since the client is disconnected. all the hub class can offer you is to give a chance to know some client has been disconnected.

Comment: Yes I need my client to connect to server. How can I do that in Windows service?

Comment: when the client is disconnected that means there is no way for server to access it. so you cant connect client to server with server code. O.O

Comment: How can the client can try reconnecting by itself if the connection drops as in web client. I know thre is no way for server to access to client.

Comment: are nt you reconnecting to server already? your javascript code is doing as i see. but if you want to do retry you should use window.setInterval function.

Comment: Yes I'm reconnecting to server already in my web app but I need the same functionality in my windows server client.

Comment: @anilca it's not possible as Hassan mentioned. And you said you are aware of this. Also your question misleads. C# code (service) is a server side in your case, not a client side

Comment: @Artiom no, the C# code mentioned in the question is client side. You will see that if you read the code. Anyway thanks for your help.